# Django 2.0, First Level Class View, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have created a generic view and serializer in Django 2.0, so that I don't have to repeat my self, creating CRUD views or serializers.

My views.py file of my API app

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer


class StandardListMixinCreateApiView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)


class StandardRudApiView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

This function sets The `serializer.Meta.model` of each enabled model.
The `cls parameter is one of the StandardApiViews.

```
def get_adapted_class(cls, model_class, serializer_fields='__all__'):

    class AdaptedSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = model_class

        fields = serializer_fields

    class AdaptedView(cls):
        model = model_class.__name__
        queryset = model_class.objects.all()
        serializer_class = AdaptedSerializer

    return AdaptedView
```

My urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from .views import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from .models import *

app_name = "api"
```

The models for which CRUD views get generated.

```
ENABLEDMODELS = [
    Address,
    Group,
    Permission,
    Customer,
    Employee,
    Commission,
    BugReport,
    FeatureRequest,
]

APILISTVIEWS = [get_adapted_class(
    StandardListMixinCreateApiView,
    model) for model in ENABLEDMODELS]

APIRUDVIEWS = [get_adapted_class(
    StandardRudApiView,
    model) for model in ENABLEDMODELS]
```

Adds an url route for each created ListView to the `urlpatterns`

```
# List, create views
urlpatterns = [re_path(
    f'^(?i){class_view.model}/',
    class_view.as_view(),
    name=f'{class_view.model}-list') for class_view in APILISTVIEWS]

# Retrive, update, delete views
urlpatterns += [re_path(
    f'^(?i){class_view.model}/' + r'(?P<pk>\d+)',
    class_view.as_view(),
    name=f'{class_view.model}-rud') for class_view in APIRUDVIEWS]
```

Error Messages

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/address/

Django Version: 2.0.4
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'api']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Steffen22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Steffen22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Steffen22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
156.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\Steffen22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\Steffen22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py" in rendered_content
72.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)

File "C:\Users\Steffen22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py" in render
724.         context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)

File "C:\Users\Steffen22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py" in get_context
656.         raw_data_post_form = self.get_raw_data_form(data, view, 'POST', request)

File "C:\Users\Steffen22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py" in get_raw_data_form
572.                 data = serializer.data.copy()

File "C:\Users\Steffen22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
560.         ret = super(Serializer, self).data

File "C:\Users\Steffen22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
266.                 self._data = self.get_initial()

File "C:\Users\Steffen22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in get_initial
413.             for field in self.fields.values()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/address/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: I have uploaded the project to github [link](https://github.com/Steffen70/TwiceApi)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to reuse my standard REST views, serializers and generate urls based of them.

'api/views.py'

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer


class StandardListMixinCreateApiView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)


class StandardRudApiView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'


def get_adapted_class(cls, model_class, serializer_fields='__all__'):
    class AdaptedView(cls):
        model = model_class.__name__
```

I had to override the get_serializer_class function instead of setting the serializer_class property.

```
        def get_serializer_class(self):
            class BaseSerializer(ModelSerializer):
                class Meta:
                    model = model_class
                    fields = serializer_fields
            return BaseSerializer

        def get_queryset(self):
            return model_class.objects.all()

    return AdaptedView
```

Those standard ApiViews are easy to use, you can create a new django model and add the model class to the ENABLEDMODELS list

'api/urls.py'

```
from django.urls import re_path
from .views import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from .models import *

app_name = "api"

ENABLEDMODELS = [
    Address,
    Group,
    Permission,
    Customer,
    Employee,
    Commission,
    BugReport,
    FeatureRequest,
]

APILISTVIEWS = [get_adapted_class(
    StandardListMixinCreateApiView,
    model) for model in ENABLEDMODELS]

APIRUDVIEWS = [get_adapted_class(
    StandardRudApiView,
    model) for model in ENABLEDMODELS]
```

In Django versions below 2.0, the path/re_path method is called url, if you change that it should also work in older versions.

The re_path method is used for regex routes in Django 2.0

```
# List, create views
urlpatterns = [re_path(
    f'^(?i){class_view.model}/',
    class_view.as_view(),
    name=f'{class_view.model}-list') for class_view in APILISTVIEWS]

# Retrive, update, delete views
urlpatterns += [re_path(
    f'^(?i){class_view.model}/' + r'(?P<pk>\d+)',
    class_view.as_view(),
    name=f'{class_view.model}-rud') for class_view in APIRUDVIEWS]
```